# Qt - How to Launch a Skype Session from a Desktop Application

Tags: c++, qt, desktop, skype

I am working on a standalone desktop GUI application using Qt and C++. What I would like to achieve is to click a button and launch a Skype call session or a call session using the device's native call app.

I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at [Skype Developer Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform)?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like follows

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("skype:xyz?call"));
```

[QDesktopServices::openUrl()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl)

Or launch URLs from command line via [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details)

```
QProcess::startDetached("start ms-call:settings");
```

Skype URI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuris

Default Windows Call URI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#call-app-uri-scheme